# MySQL Create Stored Procedures

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

This question might be flagged as duplicate but I really need help.

I have gone through a lot of answers of SO regarding this, and implemented the solutions, but nothing seems to work.

When creating the stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER ##
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_AddCity##
CREATE PROCEDURE 'sp_AddCity'(IN aCityName VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN
INSERT INTO City(CityName)
VALUES (aCityName);
END##
DELIMITER ;
```

I always get an error #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE PROCEDURE 'sp_AddCity'(IN aCityName VARCHAR(50)) BEGIN INSERT INTO City' at line 2.

Any idea where my syntax or any error is? Been struggling for a while now as I am new to MySQL.

I am using MySQL Server and attempting to create the procedures using SQL in PHPMyAdmin.

Thank You

Comment: Remove the single quotes.  Only use single quotes for string and date constants.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I just tried it but still gives me the same error message.

Comment: What if you try without the DROP line first?

Comment: @JacobH that worked. Is there any other way I can implement the DROP line? I created a small C# Winforms App to convert my SQL Server Procedures to MySQL Server Procedures. It works now but now errors might pop up if it already exists?

Comment: Do you need a space after sp_AddCity ## with your delimiter? Something is clearly up with that line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From MySQL-CLI the stored procedure is created as expected:

```sql
mysql> SELECT VERSION();
+-----------+
| VERSION() |
+-----------+
| 5.7.18    |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER ##

mysql> DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `sp_AddCity`##
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_AddCity`(IN `aCityName` VARCHAR(50))
    -> BEGIN
    ->   INSERT INTO `City`(`CityName`)
    ->   VALUES (`aCityName`);
    -> END##
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER ;

mysql> CALL `sp_AddCity`('CityName');
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table '_.City' doesn't exist
```

In phpMyAdmin you must set the `DELIMITER`, as seen in the image:

[image: phpMyAdmin-Delimiter]